# Como armazenar data/hora de alteração no BD utilizando Hibernate Envers?

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate

Preciso manter um log de todas as transações de uma entidade com o Hibernate Envers. Configurei o persistence.xml conforme abaixo:

```
        <!-- Configurações do Envers -->
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
```

Criei uma classe Autor conforme abaixo:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Entity
@Audited
public class Autor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor")
    private List<Livro> livro;

    public Autor() {

    }

    public Autor(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<Livro> getLivro() {
        return livro;
    }

    public void setLivro(List<Livro> livro) {
        this.livro = livro;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Autor [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", livro=" + livro + "]";
    }
}
```

Verificando o que ocorreu no Banco de Dados depois de algumas inserções e alterações em alguns registros, observei que realmente estão sendo auditadas as modificação na tabela, mas não estou encontrando uma forma de armazenar da data e hora de cada uma das modificações. Existe alguma anotação que possa ser colocada na classe que registre estas informações?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação do Hibernate Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#preface), a data de cada revisão é armazenada nas tabelas de auditoria.

## Consultar a data de revisão

Você pode obter a data de uma revisão através do método [`getRevisionDate()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReader.html#getRevisionDate%28java.lang.Number%29), que recebe o número da revisão como parâmetro.

Além disso, a [documentação também diz](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#revisionlog) que é possível redefinir a tabela e os campos de auditoria com a anotação `@RevisionEntity`. A anotação `@RevisionTimestamp` pode redefinir o campo onde a data é armazenada.

Resumidamente, você pode sobrescrever a tabela padrão. Exemplo:

```java
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(ExampleListener.class)
public class ExampleRevEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long timestamp;

    // Getters, setters, equals, hashCode ...
}
```

Veja [este artigo](http://hantsy.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/auditing-with-hibernate-envers.html) para maiores detalhes.

## Armazenar a data na própria tabela

Para armazenar a data das alterações na própria entidade, você pode criar um atributo de data e preenchê-lo com a data de alteração através de um [Interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html).